# How to use 'debug()' with 'undefined()' parser

Tags: dart, petitparser

I'm trying to debug an `undefined` parser in petitparser.

See the code without `debug` first:

```dart
import "package:petitparser/petitparser.dart";

main() {
  var mynum = undefined();
  var parser = string("abc").map((s) {
    mynum.set(string("888"));
    return s;
  }) & mynum;

  var result = parser.parse("abc888");
  print(result);
}
```

It prints:

```
Success[1:7]: [abc, 888]
```

But if I add `debug`:

```dart
import "package:petitparser/petitparser.dart";

main() {
  var mynum = undefined();
  var parser = string("abc").map((s) {
    mynum.set(string("888"));
    return s;
  }) & mynum;

  var result = debug(parser).parse("abc888");
  print(result);
}
```

It will fail:

```
Instance of 'SequenceParser'
  Instance of 'ActionParser'
    Instance of 'PredicateParser'[abc expected]
    Success[1:4]: abc
  Success[1:4]: abc
  Instance of 'SetableParser'
    Instance of 'FailureParser'[undefined parser]
    Failure[1:4]: undefined parser
  Failure[1:4]: undefined parser
Failure[1:4]: undefined parser
Failure[1:4]: undefined parser
```

Is there anything wrong in my usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of `Parser debug(Parser)` doesn't work well with self-modifying parsers. Its implementation uses `Parser transformParser(Parser, Function)` that creates a transformed copy of the complete grammar graph. Thus, you action function doesn't have any effect on the running code as it modifies the unused old version of the grammar.

I can think of a way to fix the problem (debug could modify the parser in-place), but that seems to have other disadvantages. Care to file and issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/renggli/PetitParserDart) to discuss this further?

Comment: Can't visit github these days, I will file one later